# Border width suddenly not updating

Tags: wpf

This is very wierd. The code was working find but suddenly the width of Border is not updating anymore. I undo everything but still can't get it to work.

I narrowed it down to this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Thumb DragStarted="shiftStartDragStart" DragDelta="breakStartDragDelta" DragCompleted="shiftStartDragEnd"
        Margin="{Binding StartSeconds, Converter={StaticResource StartSecondsToMargin}}">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="#AC22" CornerRadius="3,0,0,3" 
                    Height="17" Margin="0,10,0,0" MinWidth="5">
                    <Border.Width>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DurationToWidth}">
                            <Binding Path="StartSeconds"/>
                            <Binding Path="EndSeconds"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.Width>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</Canvas>
```

As you see it's a thumb with a border inside it, when user drags it, the events change `EndSeconds` and therefore `Border.Width` changes.

```
public class DurationToWidth : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((int)values[1] - (int)values[0]) / 120;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I can see that `DurationToWidth`  is returning the correct value. but I don't have any idea why the `Width` of Border is shown as its `MinWidth`.

I've uploaded an image of how it's behaving now and how it was behaving before:

[image]

---

### Any, Any idea at all?

Comment: Show your value converter.

Comment: If converter returns a value less than MinValue, the MinValue will be taken. So the question is what value does converter return? :)

Comment: It's a positive integer value.

Comment: Thanks. your comment led to solving of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I changed

```
return ((int)values[1] - (int)values[0]) / 120;
```

to

```
return ((int)values[1] - (int)values[0]) / 120d;
```

and it's working as intended. it seems that for some reason an integer value as Width "sometimes" causes problems.

Comment: I think your problem wasn't integer widths, it's integer division which gets truncated. So, for example, if the numerator is < 120, then after dividing by 120, you get 0.

Comment: I checked its output it was 57 at one time.